# list a = list b vs list a = list b[:]

Tags: python-2.7, list

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
b[0] = 10
print a
```

I haven't touched the numbers in list a, but they still change. Why does this happen? 
Also, this seems to return the expected result:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a[:]
b[0] = 10
print a
```

Can somebody tell me what [:] does and why the first code changes a?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have variables in the traditional sense. When you create something with `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` you are just creating a new "tag" a that points to that list.

So `b = a` is just creating a new tag named b that points to the **same** list. If you alter b, you alter a.

In your second example, `b = a[:]`, `[:]` is "slicing" the list which, in this case, would return all the values of the list, thus b now points to it's own copy of [1, 2, 3, 4], rather than a's copy.

If you were to do something like `b = a[1:3]` you could get a better idea of what the slice operator does.